# cant download and instantiate 3d model from firebase storage to unity

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage, vuforia

**i have put my 3d models in an assetbundle and stored it in firebase storage.when the app runs i want to load the 3d model from firebase and i want the 3d model to be a child of the main camera.but unfortunately it does not work.when i run the app i get the storage reference url from debug.log in the console but nothing is downloaded i debuged the code as well and found no errors.this is for my final year project so please any help is appreciated**

```
using Firebase.Storage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Loadmodel2 : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
public GameObject test;



void Start()
{
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;

    Firebase.Storage.StorageReference reference =
    storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://fit-union-221609.appspot.com/assettest1/myasset");

    reference.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith((Task<Uri> task) => {
        if (!task.IsFaulted && !task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.Log("Download URL: " + task.Result);

            // ... now download the file via WWW or UnityWebRequest.
            StartCoroutine(Loadcoroutine(task.Result));

        }
    });

}



IEnumerator Loadcoroutine(Uri uri)
{

    using (var www = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(uri))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);


        }
        else
        {

            AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(www);

            var mya1 = bundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>("BarbarianVariant");
            yield return mya1;

            var obj = Instantiate((GameObject)mya1.asset);
            obj.transform.parent = test.transform;


        }
    }


}
}
```

**this is what i want to achieve**
 [image: this is what i want to achieve]

[image]

Comment: Is "gs://fit-union-221609.appspot.com/assettest1/myasset" a google cloud storage location? gs:// only works for google storage.

Comment: then what should i do .i followed this documentation- https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/download-files  and it seems like you can use it

Answer (score 1):

According to google's documentation:

> Your files are stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket. The files in this bucket are presented in a hierarchical structure, just like the file system on your local hard disk, or the data in the Firebase Realtime Database. By creating a reference to a file, your app gains access to it. These references can then be used to upload or download data, get or update metadata or delete the file. A reference can either point to a specific file or to a higher level node in the hierarchy.

Your code that references "gs://fit-union-221609.appspot.com/assettest1/myasset" does not appear to reference a hierarchical cloud storage bucket. Consider changing to an HTTPs reference, or get the formal gs hierarchy from your google console.

Additionally, asset bundles typically have a file extension that you should include in your URI.

---

### Update

After further understanding on my part, it looks like the gs URL is correct. However, looking at the screenshot it looks like the gameObject is not enabled. That's probably the problem.

Comment: how do i change it to a https reference and what is the formal gs hierarchy

Comment: Your files are stored in a google storage bucket, correct? @malithpriyashan

Comment: The hierarchy is just "gs://<name of bucket>/<folder(s)>/<filename>", for you I would guess "gs://assettest1/myasset" @malithpriyashan

Comment: Take a screenshot of your google storage bucket please @malithpriyashan

Comment: i updated my reference-storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://assettest1/myasset"); but after i do it gives me two errors                                                                                              1)Unable to create StorageReference from URL gs://assettest1/myasset. URL specifies a different bucket (assettest1) than this instance (fit-union-221609.appspot.com)
2)ArgumentException: URL gs://assettest1/myasset does not match the storage URL gs://fit-union-221609.appspot.com

Comment: Ahh, the url you had originall is correct, then. If you click on the myasset item in your firebase console, it should have a "storage location" URI. Can you confirm that is the same?

Comment: My friend. Your "Loadmodel2" script is not enabled on your gameObject. @malithpriyashan

Comment: no bro i did enable it i was using a different script to take that photo it was from a local url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203048/discussion-between-malith-priyashan-and-erik-overflow).